# Alternate WMTS layers for world imagery

Tags: geospatial

The WMTS url for ESRI imagery is `http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml`

Does anyone know of any other WMTS urls for world imagery?

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example access recent global satellite image/LC-maps/NDVI etc. from ESA's Sentinel 2 at https://services.terrascope.be/wms/v2.